# How to loop through the inner nodes in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to loop through the XML which will have multiple inner nodes. I have a sample xml given below

```
    <?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8" ?>
    <TestUser>
      <Users>
        <UserData name="test123" address="USA"/>
        <UserCommunication>
          <Communication mode="Te" value="123456879"/>
          <Qualification>
            <PG value="No"></PG>
          </Qualification>
            <Qualification>
            <UG value="YES"></UG>
          </Qualification>
        </UserCommunication>
      </Users>
      <Users>
        <UserData name="test124" address="UK"/>
        <UserCommunication>
          <Communication mode="Te" value="1567894525"/>
          <Qualification>
            <PG value="No"></PG>
          </Qualification>
           <Qualification>
            <UG value="YES"></UG>
          </Qualification>
        </UserCommunication>
      </Users>
      <Users>
        <UserData name="test125" address="INDIA"/>
        <UserCommunication>
          <Communication mode="Te" value="5465897845"/>
          <Qualification>
            <PG value="YES"></PG>
          </Qualification>
           <Qualification>
            <UG value="YES"></UG>
          </Qualification>
        </UserCommunication>
      </Users>
    </TestUser>
```

The Output should be in text view as below

```
test123 USA Te 123456879 No YES  
test124 UK Te 1567894525 No YES  
test125 INDIA Te 5465897845 YES No
```

I also required it in HTML View.

Can anyone help me to get this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 you can simply use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Users/string-join(.//@*, ' ')" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result is

```
test123 USA Te 123456879 No YES
test124 UK Te 1567894525 No YES
test125 INDIA Te 5465897845 YES YES
```

If you want HTML output then you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <body>
           <pre>
             <xsl:value-of select="//Users/string-join(.//@*, ' ')" separator="&#10;"/>
           </pre>
         </body>
       </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to use the same approach or of course write a template to match and map `Users` to HTML `tr` elements and a template to match and map `Users//*/@*` to HTML `td` elements.

Comment: Can I have this in HTML view with the label?

Comment: Hi, Martin, I am getting an error of "Expected end of the expression, found '('."  while checking the XSLT of the text view.

Comment: It is XSLT 2.0 so you will need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Hi Martin, Can I have this XML to display in a simple HTML view?